# Looking for more information about these two hypotheses

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, time, universe

[Big Lurch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Lurch_%28cosmology%29) - This was one I read about in a special issue of Scientific American from 2014. It was explained as

> *The Big Lurch is a theoretical scientific model suggested as one of the possibilities for ultimate fate of the universe. Matter works itself up into a frenzy and forces governing the universe grow infinitely building up infinite pressure while the density and cosmic expansion rate remain in steady state. The consequences for time are unclear in this scenario. According to astronomical calculations, there is a finite probability of this scenario actually happening and relatively soon, in as little as about a few million years.*

I can't seem to find anymore information, it probably doesn't help that it also the name of a rapper.

4D Black Hole - The other I have read about in a few online articles, it was about the possibility that our universe existed on the event horizon of a 4D black hole.

If anyone can point me to a good source for more info I would appreciate it.

Comment: There is a wikipedia article on the big lurch that I found by googling the phrase in this phrase in the curly braces: {"The Big Lurch" -rap}. In google the quote will group search terms and the minus sign will omit search results with a given term (in this case omitting "rap"). There are three references in the wikipedia article, do those suit you?

Comment: I wish it did, I've seen the wiki page and tried a bunch of different searches, I was asking here as a last resort. Thnx neway though.